# undefined method `original_filename' for Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Can't seem to identify why I would be getting a undefined method original_filename, trying to do a file upload that checks the file extensions. Any ideas where im going wrong here

```
class SpreadsheetTagService 
  include Roo

  def initialize(uploaded_file)
    open_spreadsheet(File.new(uploaded_file.tempfile.path))
    read_file(open_spreadsheet)
  end 

  private 
    def read_file(file)
      @spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)

      @spreadsheet.each_with_pagename do |name,sheet|    
        Rails.logger.debug( sheet )
      end    
    end

    def open_spreadsheet(file)
      case File.extname(file.path)
        when ".csv" then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
        when ".xls" then Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
        when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
        else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
      end
    end
end
```

Controller

```
class SpreadsheetServiceController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create    
    parser = SpreadsheetTagService.new(params[:spreadsheet][:file])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.all {render :json => 'Done'}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `file.original_filename` - what original_filename means? a method, an attribute?

Comment: depends, if you really need to raise that error, you have to keep it, but also you'll have to write that method that gets the file name. If you don't care about the error you can remove it.

Comment: @rmagnum2002 I don't really need to raise the error. This is what im finding difficult now. Writting a method that gets the file extension. To fit in with what i got

Comment: and if you remove that line everything works fine?

Comment: @rmagnum2002 I initially started out with https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6132045 this worked however you will see on L5 that the issue here was that when I was uploading a `.csv` or any other format it was saving the file as import-tags.xls when I want it to determine the file extension

Comment: join this chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34635/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-17995340-undefined-method-original-filename-fo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me, removed the `#{file.original_filename}` from raise exception, modified the code so the file extension is saved properly:

```
class SpreadsheetTagService
  include Roo

  def initialize(uploaded_file)
    ext = File.extname(uploaded_file.original_filename)
    @tmp_destination = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/tag-import#{ext}"
    @file_path = save_file_to_tmp(uploaded_file)
    @file = File.new(@file_path)
    read_file(@file)
  end

  private
  def save_file_to_tmp(uploaded_file)
    FileUtils.mv(uploaded_file.tempfile, @tmp_destination )
    @tmp_destination
  end

  def read_file(file)
    @spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    @spreadsheet.each_with_pagename do |name,sheet|
      Rails.logger.debug( sheet )
    end
  end

  def open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.path)
    when ".csv" then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xls" then Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    else raise "Unknown file type"
    end
  end
end
```